# MYSQL - Use innerjoin and filter records

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

I have two mysql tables

```
Students
StudentNo  StudentName
1000       Harvey Specter
1002       Mike Ross
1003       Louis Litt

fees
ORnum  StudentNo AmtPd     PaymentMode
1      1001      1600.00   Cash
2      1002      3000.00   Installment
3      1002      5000.00   Installment
4      1002      1500.00   Installment
5      1003      10500.00  Cash
```

Using an `INNER JOIN`, I am looking for the following output

```
Student Name   Amount   Mode of Payment
Mike Ross      3000     Installment  
Mike Ross      5000     Installment
Mike Ross      1500     Installment
```

Comment: click enter image description to view my problem in subquery thanks :D

Comment: Show us instead what you have tried. Nobody's gonna do your homework.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to join mysql tables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2501625/how-to-join-mysql-tables)

Comment: @Chris Well, someone will :-(

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is an `INNER JOIN` between the student and table fees table. You are looking to filter using the `WHERE` clause.

```
SELECT s.studentName as Student_Name, f.amount as Amount, f.PaymentMode as Mode of Payment 
FROM students s
INNER JOIN fees f
ON s.StudentNo = f.StudentNo
WHERE s.studentName = 'Mike Ross'
```

Please take a look at this SQL Fiddle

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3ae1a2/3/0

Comment: sir my professor want is to get it by using subquery and not a inner join